# Type identity rule and its violation

Tags: c++, types, undefined-behavior, linkage

Below some code violating the type identity rule ([on ideone](http://ideone.com/dGpHmJ)):

```
#include <iostream>

void foo()
{
    typedef int I;
    extern I a; //now a is denoting an entity, which is a member of global scope
    std::cout << a;
}

typedef char I;
I a; //definition of a

int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

The type identity rule(sec. 3.6/10 N3797):

> After all adjustments of types (during which typedefs (7.1.3) are
>   replaced by their definitions), the types specified by all
>   declarations referring to **a given variable or function shall be**
>   **identical**, except that declarations for an array object can specify
>   array types that differ by the presence or absence of a major array
>   bound (8.3.4). **A violation of this rule on type identity does not**
>   **require a diagnostic.**

I understand that violation of that rule does not require a diagnostic. But why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quoted rule means that your violation invokes **Undefined Behavior**.

The reasons for not fully-specifying behavior are:

- Ease of implementation.
- Efficiency of the program.
- Catering to differing existing implementations.
- Allowing for extensions and future evolution.

In your case, most object-file types will not contain the neccessary information to diagnose your error if it is distributed acrross multiple implementation units.
That makes it hard to impossible to diagnose.

Anyway, as C++ does not contain any method to access different objects with the same name, putting that information into the object files is not a good idea, especially as the linker would then have to know *all* the rules C++ uses for exceptions and corner-cases.